# React nested component not updating with props change?

Tags: reactjs

This is an oft-searched issue, but I don't seem to be running into the common pitfalls (as far as I can tell).

I have a main component which controls all state. It has a method which is passed in as props to its child component for updating its state that looks like this:

```
changeAttackerAI = (target, index) => {
    this.setState(update(this.state.attackers,
        {
            [index]: {$set: {'ai': {[target.name]: target.value}}},
        }
    ))
}
```

Nested beneath this parent component I have another which exists just to loop through and output a list. Looks like this:

```
class Attackers extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="attackers">
                {this.props.models.map((model, index) => {
                    console.log(model)
                    return <Attacker key={index}
                                index={index}
                                modelData={model}
                                removeAttacker={this.props.removeAttacker}
                                reorderAttackers={this.props.reorderAttackers}
                                changeAttackerAI={this.props.changeAttackerAI}
                            />
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When changeAttackerAI is called, this console.log runs and my updated data is available.

And finally I have the component that refuses to update. Its render function is never called after the initial render, and componentWillReceiveProps or similar never get called. Looks like this:

```
class Attacker extends Component {

    removeAttacker = () => {
        this.props.removeAttacker(this.props.index)
    }

    changeAttackerAI = (e) => {
        this.props.changeAttackerAI(e.target, this.props.index)
    }

    radioButtonOption = (name, value, label) => {
        const existingValue = _.get(this.props.modelData, 'ai.' + name, null)
        return <label><input type="radio" name={name} checked={existingValue === value} value={value} onChange={this.changeAttackerAI} /> {label}</label>
    }

    render() {
        const {isDragging, connectDragSource, connectDropTarget, modelData} = this.props

        console.log(modelData)

        const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1

        return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
            <div className="attacker" style={{'opacity': opacity}}>
                {modelData.modelName}
                <button onClick={this.removeAttacker}>x</button>
                <div className="boost_hit">
                    <h3>Boost Hit</h3>
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_hit', 'none', 'None')}
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_hit', 'all', 'All')}
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_hit', 'initials', 'Initials')}
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_hit', 'chain_attack', 'Chain Attack')}
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="free_hit_boosts" value="1" onChange={this.changeAttackerAI} /> Free boosts?</label>
                </div>
                <div className="boost_damage">
                    <h3>Boost Damage</h3>
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_damage', 'none', 'None')}
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_damage', 'all', 'All')}
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_damage', 'initials', 'Initials')}
                    {this.radioButtonOption('boost_damage', 'chain_attack', 'Chain Attack')}
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="free_damage_boosts" value="1" onChange={this.changeAttackerAI} /> Free boosts?</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        ));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you simplify your code to include only the parts relevant to the problem?

Comment: Can you highlight which component doesn't update and the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out what my issue is. I had a misunderstanding for how the immutability helper functioned. When I did this:

```
this.setState(update(this.state.attackers,
    {
        [index]: {$set: {'ai': {[target.name]: target.value}}},
    }
))
```

I was overwriting my state with a subset of a my state.

What I needed was:

```
    this.setState(update(this.state,
        {
            attackers: {
                [index]: {'ai': {$merge: {[target.name]: target.value}}},
            }
        }
    ))
```

I believe the exact issue was that the component was first drawn with the original state, and then I wiped out the original references which caused it to draw. I would think this would cause it to be removed, but apparently not.